# Copy String to StringGrid?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I would like to copy the contents of a Memo to a TStringGrid.

If there is a space or gap between the strings then that word should be added to its own cell in the StringGrid.

So, suppose my Memo which is Wordwrapped contains some information like so:

[image]

How could I copy that information into a StringGrid?

For the purpose of this example I have made a sample Image to illustrate how the result should be:

[image]

It is important to know that I will not always know the amount of columns to use, if for example the Memo is loaded from a text file.

Maybe a predefined amount of columns would be better such as 5 or 6 columns. The amount of rows will also be unknown.

How may I do this?

Comment: What if the number of cells in the string grid is insufficient? Should the number of columns or the number of rows increase (or both, and if so, how?), or should the remaining words be ignored?

Comment: I think the number of rows would be better to increase/add - that way I could keep the width of the grid to an acceptable size. I think that is better than adding more and more columns to keep the grid from been to wide.

Comment: Does a Windows `EDIT` control even expose information about the wrapping. If you can't ask the control to tell you how it has wrapped the text then you are pretty much out of luck.

Comment: +1 For a question with multiple creative solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I got you right, then this should do it:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
type
  TWordPos = record
    Start, &End: integer;
  end;
const
  ALLOC_BY = 1024;
var
  Words: array of TWordPos;
  ActualLength, i: integer;
  txt: string;
  ThisWhite, PrevWhite: boolean;
begin

  ActualLength := 0;
  txt := Memo1.Text;
  PrevWhite := true;
  for i := 1 to Length(txt) do
  begin
    ThisWhite := Character.IsWhiteSpace(txt[i]);
    if PrevWhite and not ThisWhite then
    begin
      if ActualLength = Length(Words) then
        SetLength(Words, Length(Words) + ALLOC_BY);
      Words[ActualLength].Start := i;
      inc(ActualLength);
      PrevWhite := false;
    end else if (ActualLength>0) and ThisWhite then
      Words[ActualLength - 1].&End := i;
    PrevWhite := ThisWhite;
  end;

  SetLength(Words, ActualLength);

  StringGrid1.RowCount := Ceil(Length(Words) / StringGrid1.ColCount);

  for i := 0 to Length(Words) - 1 do
  begin
    StringGrid1.Cells[i mod StringGrid1.ColCount, i div StringGrid1.ColCount] :=
      Copy(Memo1.Text, Words[i].Start, Words[i].&End - Words[i].Start);
  end;

end;
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `&End`. Yuch. Just because you can doesn't mean you should!

Comment: That is exactly right thank you so much Andreas. How do you experts do these things?? You always make it seem so simple and effortless!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why is doing this a bad thing?

Comment: Because it's a little used and obscure syntax that makes it harder for the human to parse the code.

Comment: @blobby This routine would be better split into two. One to perform the tokenisation or splitting. And one to populate the grid. That way you can reuse the tokenisation. However, there must be good tokenisers available rather than having to roll your own. Anyone know if Delphi has this thing readily available in the rtl, or if there is a good lightweight 3rd party lib?

Comment: What is a tokeniser, does that mean special characters? In my case the space between the letters is a token?

Comment: The words are the tokens. A tokeniser takes a stream of text as input and emits a sequence of tokens. Try a websearch to learn more but remember to use the American spelling tokenizer.

Answer (score 5):

There is a `Tokenizer` (as commented by David) in the RTL.
It will split a text into words, using a delimiter of your choice.

This example is from a comment by Olaf Moinen at an article by Zarko Gaijic : [how-to-split-a-delphi-string-to-words-tokens.htm](http://delphi.about.com/b/2008/06/28/how-to-split-a-delphi-string-to-words-tokens.htm).

```
uses HTTPUtil;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LTokenizer: IStringTokenizer;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  LTokenizer := StringTokenizer(Edit1.Text, ' ');
  while LTokenizer.hasMoreTokens do
  Memo1.Lines.Add(LTokenizer.nextToken);
end;
```

It will take the text from the edit control and put it into a memo.
I will leave it as an exercise to do the same thing from a memo to a stringgrid.

Comment: +1 Now that's what I'm talkin' about! to borrow a quote from Sebatien Vettel. Very nice.

Comment: +1 thanks for sharing LU RD. When I can understand it and how it works I am sure it will come in handy.

Comment: Great to know there's a rtl tokeniser, I've used the one from hyperstr for years, but it's no longer supported so not ported to D2010.

Answer (score 2):

`TStringGrid` has the feature to fill *non-existing* cells, cells which are beyond `ColCount * RowCount`. Thus it is not necessary to count the words prior to filling out the string grid.

Then, a straightforward approach results in:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  WordCount: Integer;
  WordStart: Integer;
  S: String;
  I: Integer;
begin
  WordCount := 0;
  WordStart := 1;
  S := Memo.Text + ' ';
  for I := 1 to Length(S) do
    if S[I] = ' ' then
    begin
      if WordStart <> I then
      begin
        Grid.Cells[WordCount mod Grid.ColCount, WordCount div Grid.ColCount] :=
          Copy(S, WordStart, I - WordStart);
        Inc(WordCount);
      end;
      WordStart := I + 1;
    end;
  Grid.RowCount := ((WordCount - 1) div Grid.ColCount) + 1;
end;
```

**Note:** To prevent the extra memory allocation for the text (due to the addition of `' '`), add the last word to the grid after the loop instead.

#### Bonus feature:

To be able adjusting the column count, subclass the string grid as follows and all cells will be rearranged automatically:

```
type
  TStringGrid = class(Grids.TStringGrid)
  protected
    procedure SizeChanged(OldColCount, OldRowCount: Integer); override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ...

procedure TStringGrid.SizeChanged(OldColCount, OldRowCount: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if OldColCount < ColCount then
  begin
    for I := 0 to OldColCount * OldRowCount - 1 do
      Cells[I mod ColCount, I div ColCount] :=
        Cells[I mod OldColCount, I div OldColCount];
  end
  else if OldColCount > ColCount then
  begin
    for I := OldColCount * OldRowCount - 1 downto 0 do
      Cells[I mod ColCount, I div ColCount] :=
        Cells[I mod OldColCount, I div OldColCount];
  end;
  if OldColCount <> OldRowCount then
    for I := OldColCount * OldRowCount to ColCount * RowCount - 1 do
      Cells[I mod ColCount, I div ColCount] := '';
end;
```

Comment: Not wanting to take anything away from the other answers you are right NGLN I perhaps accepted too quick. It suprised me that there a few special ways of doing this. +1 for your method and input.